# Difference between .changes and .dsc files when manually updating a package?

Tags: debian, packaging

What is the difference between .changes and .dsc file?

[Debian Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-debiansourcecontrolfiles) says about required field set, but misses the essence and the meaning on the whole. Why have two (actually there are three) when you can have the only one?

Can this .changes file be derived from .dsc (or vice versa)?
What is the transformation process?

**Why?** I am trying to create Python script that automates updating of pure Python packages for Debian or Ubuntu systems. It needs to be cross-platform, because it is quite common to develop Python stuff on systems without classic Debian toolchain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Debian source control file `.dsc` is one of the three files which is part of a Debian package source. The other two are the original upstream source tarball, which typically is of the form `*.orig.tar.gz`, and a diff file, which may be a file like `*.diff.gz` (old style), or `debian.tar.gz` (3.0 (quilt) source format).

In both cases (old-style `diff.gz` or newer `debian.tar.gz`), the original tarball is unpacked, and the diff is applied, resulting in a source directory with a `debian` subdirectory.
In the former case, patches applied by Debian to the upstream sources are applied directly to the source. In the latter case, patches applied by Debian to the upstream sources live inside the `debian/patches` directory.

The `dsc` file contains information about the other two files mentioned above, including checksums, so that corruption can be detected during the unpacking process.

The `changes` file is similar, but also contains information about the binary (`deb`) files. Its purpose is different - it is used by the archive software to keep track of updates in an archive, which includes both source and binary packages. From a user point of view, the `changes` file is not so interesting, unless you are planning to maintain your own package archive.

Both the `changes` and `dsc` files is obtained when binary packages are built from the Debian sources. So, in practice, a user does not need to edit either `dsc` or `changes` files.

NOTE: A typical way to run a Debian package build process is by doing `debuild -uc -us`, using the `debuild` script from the [devscripts](http://packages.qa.debian.org/d/devscripts.html) package. This creates the following files (for source format 3.0): `*.changes`, `*.dsc`, `*.debian.tar.gz`, `*.build` (the build log) and the Debian binary files. Sometimes, the `*.dsc` and `*.debian.tar.gz` will already exist if the source directory was unpacked from pre-existing Debian sources, but will be overwritten if the version number is not changed.

Comment: "In both cases" - I am missing - what are these both cases here?

Comment: `dsc` doesn't just contain checksums - there is a lot of other duplicate headers. Why duplicate the info? It should match the contents of package? Why not just add this info into `debian/control` and make .dsc a single checksum file?

Comment: So, to create `changes`, I just need to get `dsc` and add there data for `deb` that I've build. Right?

Comment: @techtonik The two cases are the kind of Debian diff against the original source (`diff.gz` or `debian.tar.gz`). I modified the question.

Comment: @techtonik Good question (about why dsc has that extra information). I think because in the public archive, the information in the control file is not available; it is hidden inside a diff. So I think tools look for the control-type information by referencing the `.dsc` file. For example, `apt-cache showsrc`, `apt-get source` and `apt-get build-dep` probably ultimately get their information from the `dsc` files, possibly via a local cache; e.g. `/var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin`. I don't actually know this for sure - I haven't actually verified it. If anyone has more information, please comment.

Comment: @techtonik: To create the `changes` file, you need to build the package, as described above.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Because all files are text, and I am not on Debian, I'd like to try and build them manually.